# One loop over multiple Ansible tasks

Tags: loops, ansible

I've created an Ansible playbook that creates a cloud instance and then installs some programs on the instance. I want to run this playbook multiple times (without using a bash script). Is it possible to use a loop to loop over those two tasks together (I.E. One loop for two tasks?). All I've been able to find so far is one loop for each individual task

Comment: It's too bad you can't use `with_items` with [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_blocks.html), which seems like it would be an idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No that's currently not possible. `with_items` used to work with the `include` statement in previous versions of Ansible but was unfortunately dropped.

Though it will be brought back in Ansible 2.0, see slide 14/15 of [What's New in v2 - AnsibleFest London 2015](http://www.slideshare.net/jimi-c/whats-new-in-v2-ansiblefest-london-2015)

[image: Screenshot from linked AnsibleFest slides]

You could try to work with the [v2 branch from github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/v2_final), the feature should be available in there.

What you can do with 1.9.1 is to move your tasks into a role and reference this role multiple times in your playbook.

Comment: Dude, what is up with the screenshot?

Comment: @masterial if you follow the "what's new in v2" link it looks like it's just a slide from the slide-deck. slides just have a plain black background and don't seem to fill the whole space all the time

Answer (score 30):

An update:

> In 2.0 you are able to use `with_` loops and task includes (but not playbook includes), this adds the ability to loop over the set of tasks in one shot. There are a couple of things that you need to keep in mind, a included task that has it’s own `with_` loop will overwrite the value of the special item variable. So if you want access to both the include’s item and the current task’s item you should use `set_fact` to create a alias to the outer one.:

> ```
> - include_tasks: test.yml
> ```

```
  with_items:
    - 1
    - 2
    - 3
```

> in test.yml:

> ```
> - set_fact: outer_loop="{{item}}"
> - debug: msg="outer item={{outer_loop}} inner item={{item}}"
> ```

```
  with_items:
    - a
    - b
    - c
```

Source: [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)

Comment: This has been improved in 2.1, with a feature to specify a different variable name for the outer loop - see [loop control section](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) of Ansible docs.  There are related improvements in 2.2 in same section.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to do this by recursively including the same yaml file based on a condition. Here is the gist: https://gist.github.com/ParagDoke/5ddfc3d5647ce9b0110d1b9790090092. Effectively, in your playbook, include a file with some vars:

```
  - name: Invoke poller
    vars:
      some_condition: '"failed" not in response.content and response.json.status=="running"'
    include_tasks: status-poller.yml
```

Then in `status-poller.yml`, include itself:

```
- include_tasks: includes/status-poller.yml
  when: some_condition
```