# Ansible iterate over hash with condition

Tags: python, configuration, ansible, devops

I've been using ansible for quite a while and have stumbled across an issue that is beyond my googling skills. I have a vars structure as in this snippet:

```
artifacts:

  - name: demo
    version: v1

    templates:
      - source: "/opt/source/file.txt"
        destination: "/opt/destination/file.txt"
```

I would now like to iterate over this structure as in the next snippet:

```
- name: "Archive files"
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ item.1.destination }}"
    dest: "/some/backup/dir/"
    archive: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: item[1].destination.isfile
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ artifacts }}"
    - templates
```

It obviously fails because of a wrongly defined when condition:

```
  when: item[1].destination.isfile
```

I am looking for the most elegant way of writing my playbook that would allow to check if the file that is defined in the artifacts' templates destinations exists in the filesystem. I was initially thinking of using stat module and adding a block in which i would iterate over same set of subelements, but that is not currently supported by the ansible according to this link: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13262

Comment: You can't attach something which looks somewhat like a method of os.path object in Python to a string and expect it to work in a Jinja2 template.　・　Reading your code, it's difficult to tell what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: The bigger picture is that I have a fixed structure of vars that I need to use. Those files should already be placed on the destination server. There is a corner case in which someone adds a template entry for file which is not on the destination server yet and I would like to secure my playbook against this case. The biggest issue here for me is finding a way of either writing it in one with_subelements statement or iterating with_subelements over 2 tasks.One would check if the file exists (stat) and the other would copy files when file exists based on the condition set in first task.

Answer (score 0):

No, this kind of `when` statement seems not possible. It should rely on already available facts.

So you either split it into two tasks like `stat` + `archive`...

Or just add `--ignore-missing-args` if you don't care about missing files, like:

```
- name: "Archive files"
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ item.1.destination }}"
    dest: "/some/backup/dir/"
    archive: yes
    rsync_opts: ['--ignore-missing-args']
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ artifacts }}"
    - templates
```

Note that `--ignore-missing-args` is available in rsync `3.06+`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately my rsync version does not support this feature so I had to stick with splitting it into two tasks. I used the method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785281/one-loop-over-multiple-ansible-tasks for iterating over multiple tasks. I find it somewhat ugly and unnecessarily complicated. Is it a proper way of handling this or there is some neater approach there that I am not familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

As per Konstantin's suggestion, I ended up with splitting this into two tasks:

```
- include: archive.yml artifact="{{item}}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ artifacts }}"
    - templates
```

archive.yml:

```
- name: "Check if the file exists"
  stat:
    path: "{{ artifact.1.destination }}"
  register: stat_result

- name: "Archive files"
  synchronize:
    src: "{{ artifact.1.destination }}"
    dest: "/some/backup/dir/"
    archive: yes
  delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  when: stat_result.stat.exists == True
```