# Convert an array to another array

Tags: ansible

I am trying to convert an **output array** to another **array**.

Suppose I have the following output from a command:

```
kube-system        extension-apiserver-authentication   6         119d
kube-system        kube-dns                             0         119d
kube-system        kube-dns-autoscaler                  1         119d
kube-system        kube-flannel-cfg                     2         119d
kube-system        kubernetes-dashboard-settings        1         29d
```

I want each element `cut -d' ' -f2` to get an array only containing the **column 2**.

Like `list.stream().map(l -> l.getName()).collect(toList())` in Java 8.

To test it locally I tried using `ls -al` as

1. `ls -al` a folder;
2. get the third column `owner` and return a list of the owners;

A demo for it will be:

---

```
- name: Run in local to test loop
  hosts: 127.0.0.1 
  connection: local

  tasks:
  - name: List a folder
    shell: ls -al .
    register: result  

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: Get Second Separated by Space
    shell: echo '{{ item }}' | cut -d' ' -f3; # trying to get column 3
    loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
    register: result # this result is not what I am after :(

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

Any idea to this?

F.Y.I

The `ls -al` output in my PC similar to:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hearen hearen     1 Sep   5 12:55 tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am solving this by `"{{ item.split()[2] }}"` instead of `cut -d' ' -f3` and there are two cases when using the *cut* element:

1. one single task, I can directly use it to get the specific `column`;

---

```
  - name: Get Second via split
    debug: 
      msg: "{{ item.split()[1] }}"
    loop: "{{ result.stdout_lines }}"
```

2. as for several tasks, I am to use **loop over block** which you can refer to [One loop over multiple Ansible tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785281/one-loop-over-multiple-ansible-tasks), [Apply with_items on multiple tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39040521/apply-with-items-on-multiple-tasks) or [How can Ansible loop over a sequence of tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701369/how-can-ansible-loop-over-a-sequence-of-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Ansible to implement code you'd write in Bash and [don't parse `ls` output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/133107).

If you want to get a list of owners, this is the way to do it:

```
- name: List a folder
  find:
    path: .
  register: find

- debug:
    msg: "{{ find.files | map(attribute='pw_name') | list }}"
```